# How to create a list of String from a list of Object using reduce in Java 8?

Tags: java

I have an object as follows:

```java
class Order {
  private String code;
  private String status;
  // Constructor, getters and setter and so on
}
```

I need to create a list of the codes, from a list of orders, which satisfy a condition.
I have implemented something similar in JavaScript and it looks like below:

```js
const codes = orders.reduce((codeList, order) => {
  if (order.status === 'NEW') return codeList.push(order.code)
  return codeList
}, [])
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you should use `collect`, not `reduce`, for this purpose:

```
List<String> codes =
    orders.stream()
          .filter(o -> o.getStatus().equals("NEW"))
          .map(Order::getCode)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I did that, but is that efficient? I mean, as far as I'm concerned, with that implementation I'm going over the array twice, but with the JS implementation only once.

Comment: Yes it is efficient.  No it is not "going over" the list twice.  It is a stream.  The input list is iterated once.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce is for aggregate values in a single result (like AVG or SUM for example).
Collect is used for aggregate values in a collection.

Java 8 Streams are often more efficient than processing on collection because they only process what you need, also allowing you to parallelize if necessary

Bye